# Problems with X Forwarding and Xming with Suse Linux and Windows 10

Tags: linux, x11, suse, xming

I am trying to setup X forwarding with PuTTY to connect to my Suse Linux VM running on Microsoft Azure Cloud. I installed Gnome on the VM and now trying to setup X forwarding so I can see the GUI apps with using Gnome on Linux.

Per some instructions, I installed Xming on my Windows 10 computer, I started it from the command line and it opened an X style window on my Windows 10 computer, but started PuTTY before starting Xming, and the instructions say start Xming first, so I exited out of the Xming window, and now Xming does nothing when trying to run it again.

I am kind of aggravated with this, I used X forwarding with PuTTY at a previous job where we were developing software on Red Hat Linux, and it worked good for running GUI apps. I have been wrestling with this Suse Linux VM for a few weeks now, and it was a big hassle trying to get the VM to work with PuTTY, but now I figured that out and can connect to the Suse Linux VM with PuTTY.

Also, I can connect to the VM using Termius, but only with version 2, not version 3 of PuTTY.

I accidentally nuked the SSH settings on the VM using VIM to edit SSH files, but was able to restore using the Azure Cloud Portal restore feature.

What happened to the Xming window that popped up the first time? and now will not pop up after I X'd out of the first window? How can I restart Xming? Could not find anything on Google on how to restart Xming? Going to reinstall if this cannot be resolved. A google search found nothing about this issue.

Comment: Ok I might close this post. To save my money with my Azure Cloud, I chose very limited resources for my Suse Linux VM. Now when I start Gnome from command line, the VM becomes really slow. Going to try xfce and rdp next.

Comment: Ok, I was able to partly resolve this issue, but still stumped by it. Since my Suse Linux Virtual Machine on Microsoft Azure Cloud comes with a support place, I opened up a support ticket with Microsoft instead of trying many unsuccessful tactics. I will come back to this issue another time and post the solution when I have it. Thank you.